# Getting "Call to undefined function: 'define': in phalanger web site

Tags: php, web, phalanger

I'm just starting out with Phalanger and hit a road block. I installed the latest from the Visual Studio Gallery and tried to create a simple web page. The sample web page that is create with a project works, but once I add to the index.php:

```
<?php
define("test","");
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

I get :

```
 Call to undefined function: 'define' in c:\users\....
```

I can't seem to find a reference on the web to this issue, so I must have a setup wrong. Almost the same code works when I do this in a console app.

Comment: [The PHP code works fine](https://3v4l.org/9sA25). The problem seems to lie with Phalanger. Contact the author of this project.

Answer (score 0):

All the functions are defined in external libraries. While it should be set by default, ensure following is in your web.config file, under phpNet/classLibrary section:

```
<phpNet><classLibrary><add assembly="PhpNetClassLibrary, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4af37afe3cde05fb">
```

Comment: Thanks, the line got remove from my config. Where does Phalanger look for dll's listed there?

Comment: Phalanger uses .NET to resolve assemblies. So in case of web application (ASP.NET pipeline), it looks in Global Assembly Cache (C:\Windows\Microsft.NET) and in web root Bin folder.